# Getting current day number with awk and date

Tags: awk, cut

The output of `date` command has two spaces when the day number is less than 10. For example

```
Mon May 31 10:24:01 +0430 2020
Mon Jun  1 10:24:01 +0430 2020
```

For the first one, `date | cut -d " " -f 3` returns 31. But, for the second one, it returns SPACE. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Why use `cut` or `awk` to get data part. Just use `date '+%d'` to always get 2 digit number.

Comment: Output current day with bash 4.2 or newer: `printf -v day '%(%-1e)T' -1; echo "$day"`

Comment: @Cyrus - now that is cool, but where in `man bash` does that come from? The only thing I can find relatively close is under **Prompting**, but that isn't it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: for `%(fmt)T` see `help printf`. For `%e` see `man 3 strftime` and for trailing `-1` see `man bash`: *-1 represents the current time, and -2  represents  the  time  the  shell was invoked*

Comment: Current day with GNU `date` without leading space: `date '+%-1d'`

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for all the pieces in one place -- silly me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simple try `awk` to get the 3rd field, which will be definitely better than `cut` command.

```
date | awk '{print $3}'
```

Now why `cut` command is not working IMHO because space between `May` and `31` is equal but space between `Jun` and `1` is not equal so you need to use `f4` in your cut command(for single digit date numbers with your current approach). Its better to use `awk` in this case.

Or In ideal scenario if you want to get only date then use `date '+%d'` to get date always in 2 digit as per @anubhava sir's comments.